# Examples directory missing in MySQL Connector\C++ (where to get them?)

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I downloaded 4 versions of MySQL [from here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) plus installed Connector\C++ via apt-get and still don't have the Connector\C++ examples directory [referred to in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-getting-started-examples.html). Unless I'm missing something, this has apparently [been a problem for *three years!*](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58127)

Is there a package to download that has the MySQL examples or a good resource available with up to date examples for MySQL Connector\C++?

Edit: I forgot to specify that I downloaded the debian version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples are in the 'examples' directory when you download the Connector/C++ source code, for example in version 1.1.3 available here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Choose source code instead of operating system in the dropdown menu.

Comment: I should have specified for debian linux. Sorry bout that. Perhaps they are in the version you downloaded but not in debian version I downloaded. You gave the same link I did, btw.

Comment: Sorry but no, the link I gave is for downloading both the binaries & source code, not that link to the handbook. Rgrds.

Comment: I gave 3 links. Yours is the same as the first one I gave. Is there a specific link on that page which should be downloaded? I just tried again and when I download, I select the operating system from the dropdown then there are two links. 64bit and 32bit release.

Comment: yes, from the combo box, select 'Source Code' not 'Windows' or a Linux  flavor, the link is http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C++/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3.tar.gz